# gitolite with http acces via LDAP does not pass the username

Tags: apache, gitolite

I'm trying to setup a git server with:

- http-access to be able to clone repositories like this:

  git clone `http://mygitserver/repository`
- have a web interface (gitweb), if possible with restrictions per user
- control access based on LDAP accounts

So far I have gitweb up and running; when I access

```
http://gitserver/
```

it asks ldap login and when I provide this; it shows all repositories (even gitolite-admin repository... not so good)

When I try to clone, I get the error:

```
fatal: http://gitserver/<reponame>.git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?
```

I dug into it and I found out that the gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh does not receive the LDAP username; so gitolite cannot grant access since the username is empty... any ideas?

here is my configuration:

my apache configuration file looks like the one here:
http://gitolite.com/gitolite/g2/ggshb.html. The most interesting part is this:

```
ScriptAliasMatch \
        "(?x)^/(.*/(HEAD | \
                        info/refs | \
                        objects/(info/[^/]+ | \
                                 [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | \
                                 pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | \
                        git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
        /srv/www/bin/gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh/$1
```

for one or another reason the parameter $1 is not passed or is empty.... in the apache log I get these lines:

```
10.1.86.100 - - [22/Jan/2014:18:09:52 +0100] "GET /git/<reponame>.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 401 - "-" "git/1.8.4"
601 10.1.86.100 - - [22/Jan/2014:18:09:57 +0100] "GET /git/<reponame>.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 401 - "-" "git/1.8.4"
602 10.1.86.100 - chris.maes [22/Jan/2014:18:09:57 +0100] "GET /git/<reponame>.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1" 200 120 "-" "git/1.8.4"
```

oh yes; my environment:
Opensuse 13.1
gitolite 2.3.1
git 1.8.4

Comment: Any reason to use an old gitolite 2.x? As for Apache I don't use `gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh`: see https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/2801e9f5366185b532300fe07e434b60a5cea030/apache/env.conf.tpl#L149-L165

Comment: I just added the repository i found; it was the last one I found available... Can this make a big difference?

Comment: The most recent one is at https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite: 3.5.1 and it is much easier to install/support/update. It doesn't need a `gitolite-suexec-wrapper.sh`: you can directly call the `gitolite-shell` script as shown in my Apache config.

Comment: I just had a discussion with a collegue: might GitLab or Gitorious be a more easy alternative to have all the features I want?

Comment: No, it is a completely different setup, with an additional database, to manage users. But GitLab has certainly a much complete set of features. It has *not*, however, custom hooks. (https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/issues/14, ie the VREFS from gitolite)

Comment: I don't really care whether the setup is different: I am not married to gitolite. I want to have:
(1) LDAP access to check out an check in
(2) a web browser with LDAP access to visualize sources

Comment: Then GitLab is a good choice. I have added in my answer a link to its LDAP config section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two solutions are:

1/ Apache + ldap, calling `gitolite-shell` (gitolie V3)

```
 ScriptAlias /hgit/ @H@/sbin/gitolite-shell/
    SetEnv GIT_HTTP_BACKEND "@H@/usr/local/apps/git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend"
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
      SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Location /hgit>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        #AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AuthName "LDAP authentication for ITSVC Smart HTTP Git repositories"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthBasicProvider myldap companyldap
```

2/ Or GitLab, which had LDAP authentication: "[setting up gitlab LDAP-authentication without special gitlab user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15321532/6309)"
See the [config `gitlab.yml` ldap section](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/68590fddd860c5d840d8f04314ed11f0d02ddd44/config/gitlab.yml.example#L118-L139).

Comment: Waw, GitLab + bitnabi is the revelation!!! I installed it using the bitnabi installer: GitLab was up and running in no time with LDAP access; I still need to do some configuration for user access and repos, but so far I am bluffed!!!