# How to create multiple users for a single GIT repository with different access permissions?

Tags: git, repository

How to create multiple users for a single GIT repository with different credentials?

i.e. I want to provide read-only access to a set of users and read-write access to another set of users.
Also, I need to give a unique username for each user in both the levels. It would be really helpful if I get the correct steps to perform this operation.

Thanks in advance.!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to install **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/)**, which allows you to declare and manage a set of users with, for instance ssh keys for authentication.

See "[How do programs like gitolite work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13320256/6309)" for more.

But you cal also plug gitolite with https, and use https authentication instead (with [LDAP for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21303301/6309)).

Gitolite is just a perl script which [deals with authorization, not authentication](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/auth.html).

Comment: It looks great. But isn't there a way to perform this without gitolite? Also, gitolite is **open source** right?

Comment: @Orochimaru no: git has no notion of authorization. Yes, gitolite is opensource.