# GitLab with LDAP Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ldap, gitlab

I am currently setting up my GitLab Server to authenticate users with LDAP. After spending hours trying to setup the authentication, now i am receiving the following error when entering the user data:

"Could not authorize you from LDAP because: "Undefined method 'persisted?' for #"

Apparently GitLab is unable to create the user in gitlab's database.

any help on how I can actually solve this issue?

Comment: we need to see the relevant code in order to help you debug it. :) Can you please edit your question and add it in?

Comment: What complex things are you doing? Normaly LDAP-authentication should work out-of-the-box with the default ldap or omniauth-configuration. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321532/setting-up-gitlab-ldap-authentication-without-special-gitlab-user

Comment: Turns out it was a problem/bug with the email address being too short. My email was SD@domain.com and it gave an error. but when I switched to a 5 character email it worked!